# Is this bad coding practice?

Tags: c, c89

I'm using PC-lint to analyze my code and theese lines are generating several errors. That makes me wonder if my coding pratice is wrong?

```
char *start;
char *end;

// Extract the phone number
start = (char*) (strchr(data, '\"') +1);
end = (char*) strchr(start, '\"');
*end = 0;
strlcpy((char*)Fp_smsSender, start , start-(end-1));
```

EDIT:
After your help i now have:

```
char *start;
char *end;

if (data != NULL)
{
  // Extract the phone number
  start = strchr(data, '\"');
  if (start != NULL)
  {
    ++start;
    end = strchr(start, '\"');

    if (end != NULL)
    {
      *end = 0;
      strlcpy((char*)Fp_smsSender, start , FP_MAX_PHONE);
    }
  }
```

How does that look?

Comment: Danger Will Robinson! Consider using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and correct any warnings.

Comment: Don't cast return values from functions. If you have warnings for such a function you probably forgot to include the relevant header file.

Comment: `*end = 0` modifies the source string. Is this what you are intended to do? If not, you could use `strncpy` (instead of `strlcpy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that what lint is complaining about is that `strchr()` might return a NULL pointer, and you're not checking for that before performing pointer arithmetic and dereferencing it.

You might want to do something like:

```
char *start;
char *end;

// Extract the phone number
start = strchr(data, '\"');
if (!start) handle_error();

++start; // skip the '\"'
end = strchr(start, '\"');
if (!end) handle_error();

*end = 0; 
strlcpy((char*)Fp_smsSender, start, size_of_Fp_smsSender_buffer);
```

Note that I changed the last parameter to the `strlcpy()` call - what that parameter is for is to specify the size of the destination buffer so you don't overrun it. The value you're passing makes no sense at all, and lint probably complained about that too. You probably meant `end-(start-1)` which might be more simply stated as `strlen(start)+1`.

Anyway, even passing in `strlen(start)+1` as the last parameter to `strlcpy()` violates the intent of the parameter, and removes the safety `strlcpy()` is supposed to provide. You might as well have simply used `strcpy(Fp_smsSender,start)` - and if you don't know how big the `Fp_smsSender` destination buffer is, you should do exactly that (or fix things so you do know how big the buffer is). It'll be more clear what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Yes, Lint complaines about possible NULL pointers. I will do the check

Comment: I'd rather see `end - start + 1` than recalculating a known length with `strlen`, but that may just be me.

Comment: @Chris - I can buy that, and I thought about putting that in the answer. But given what the problem was initially, I opted for the 'blatantly correct' expression.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: first you don't handle NULL returns from `strchr`.

Second (and more seriously), the length you pass to `strlcpy` is wrong: you would want `end - start` or something similar (you have that reversed), but more fundamentally, the length argument to `strlcpy` should be the size of the *destination* buffer, not the source string.

Comment: I can see that i have used the last argument in strlcpy wrong. Thanks.